# How to check if enum type?

Tags: php, types, enums, php-8.1

How can I tell if a variable is of type enum?

I have installed PHP 8.1 on my Ubuntu 20.04. I'm testing the new "enum" types.

Is something like that possible?

```
is_enum($var)
gettype($var) === 'enum'
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Someone told me the solution:

```php
if ($var instanceof \UnitEnum) {
   echo 'is enum';
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unitenum

Comment: Or depending on your needs, `instanceof BackedEnum`.

Comment: this always returns false for me

Answer (score 18):

use **enum_exists**, for check if is a enum.

```
if (enum_exists(Item::class)) {
    $myType = Item::Manufactured;
}
```

Comment: It also works with `enum_exists($var::class)`

Comment: Note that this also tries to autoload by default (second parameter): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.enum-exists.php

Answer (score 3):

To check if a `$var` is a `BackedEnum`, you can use this code:

```php
if ($var instanceof \BackedEnum) {
   echo 'is a backed enum';
}
```

Read more on [documentation of PHP about `BackedEnum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.backedenum.php).

Answer (score 2):

You also can check it through reflection:

```
var_dump(
    (new ReflectionClass($object::class))
        ->isEnum()
);
```